# Flutter Dio Can't Make POST Requests

Tags: android, http, flutter, server

I'm trying to perform a POST request in a Flutter application using the Dio Plugin. I have the following code and I don't seem to know why it's not working. It sends  empty data to my API.

Code:

```
Future<String> sendRequest(String phone, int status) async {
String status = '';
print(sendConnectionUrl);
String bearerToken = await Endpoints.getBearerToken();

try {
  Response response = await Dio().post(
    'https://my.web.server/api',
    data: json.encode({ "mobile": phone, "status": status }),
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearerToken
      }
    )
  );

  // The code doesnt even get here, it goes straight to the catch
  print(response.toString());
  print('status: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
  var jsonData = json.decode(response.toString());
  if (jsonData['error'] == '0') {
    status = 'ok';
  }
  else {
    status = 'failed';
  }
}
catch (e) {
  print('exception: ' + e.toString());
  Future.error(e.toString());
}

return status;
}
```

But sending the request in POSTMAN works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you're server is expecting `formData` and you're sending data via `data` params. As far as i know `Dio` doesn't support `formData` . To solve this, you should either change your API to suit this requirement or use `http`package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = 'https://example.com/whatsit/create';
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');

print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Future<String> sendRequest(String phone, int status) async {
String status = '';
print(sendConnectionUrl);
String bearerToken = await Endpoints.getBearerToken();
Formdata form=FormData.fromMap({
"mobile": phone, "status": status
})

try {
  Response response = await Dio().post(
    'https://my.web.server/api',
    data: form,
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearerToken
      }
    )
  );

  // The code doesnt even get here, it goes straight to the catch
  print(response.toString());
  print('status: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
  var jsonData = json.decode(response.toString());
  if (jsonData['error'] == '0') {
    status = 'ok';
  }
  else {
    status = 'failed';
  }
}
catch (e) {
  print('exception: ' + e.toString());
  Future.error(e.toString());
}

return status;
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
FormData form = FormData.fromMap({"url": url});
Response response = await (Dio()).post(requestUrl, data: form, cancelToken: token);
```